# How to add number in string if string is combination of letter and number?

Tags: php, string, operators

I want to increment `IDT100` this string (`IDT100, IDT101, .....IDT1000 etc`) which dynamic.

I tried below code

```
<?php

$cart_billno = "IDT100";

echo $cart_billno += 1 ;//....1st try

echo $cart_billno = $cart_billno + 1 ;//...2 nd try

?>
```

Answer i got id `1`

I check php [official site](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

then i tried

```
<?php 

$var = 1;

echo $cart_billno = $cart_billno + $var ;//......3 rd try

?>
```

Answer i got id `1`

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use preincrement instead:

```
$cart_billno = "IDT100";
echo ++$cart_billno; // IDT101
```

Or use a normal for loop:

```
$cart_billno = 'IDT';
for($i = 100; $i <= 1000; $i++) {
    echo $cart_billno.$i . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: `string++` is a nice feature.

Comment: @Prashant what happens is that `IDT100` == `0` and you are adding `(int) 1`, so it equals to `1`

Comment: @Ghost : really thank you but whats wrong in my code..i frusted for such small thing from one hour

Comment: @Prashant actually this behavior is stated in the manual. [check this out](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) how PHP handles this

Comment: @Ghost : yes, i checked but (IDT100 == 0)how can this possible?

Comment: @Prashant this is stated in the link i gaved you `The value is given by the initial portion of the string. If the string starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used. Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero). Valid numeric data is an optional sign, followed by one or more digits (optionally containing a decimal point), followed by an optional exponent. The exponent is an 'e' or 'E' followed by one or more digits.`

Answer (score 1):

```
$cart_billno = "IDT";

$i = 99;
while (++$i < 1001) {
    echo $cart_billno . $i ;
}
```

Will print IDT100 To  IDT1000

Answer (score 0):

If you need to increment the value more than 1 at the same time use something like:

```
$cart_billno = "IDT100";
echo substr($cart_billno, 0, 3) , (substr($cart_billno, 3) + 99); // IDT199
```

Which would be a cleaner solution in my opinion than increase an alphanumeric string by one.

Comment: Not getting.. can you explain ?